# How to set the directories for the header libraries, libraries , linker etc for intel math kernel version 10.1

Tags: visual-c++, math, kernel, intel, intel-mkl

I have this older version and trying to use it with Visual C++. The installer for the new version of the Intel math kernel sets the dependencies ( path to library, header files , linkers, etc. ), automatically. I am wondering if anyone has the instruction for manual adjustment of the directories for Intel Math Kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Single Dynamic Library

You can simplify your link line through the use of the Intel MKL Single Dynamic Library (SDL).

To use SDL, place libmkl_rt.so on your link line. For example:

icс application.c -lmkl_rt

SDL enables you to select the interface and threading library for Intel MKL at run time. By default, linking with SDL provides:

```
LP64 interface on systems based on the Intel® 64 architecture
Intel threading
```

To use other interfaces or change threading preferences, including use of the sequential version of Intel MKL, you need to specify your choices using functions or environment variables as explained in section Dynamically Selecting the Interface and Threading Layer.

Source: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mkl_userguide_lnx/index.htm